# Objective-C game class serialization advice (hand coded XML file)

Tags: objective-c, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I am looking to create / instantiate the levels and level enemies of a game I'm creating from an xml file at runtime that I will initially edit by hand until I have time to create a level editor. Once I have time to make the editor, I wish to automatically serialize and save my levels to disk. My enemy class uses CGPoints, floats and enums, along with basic datatypes like NSString.

Being new to objective-c, I am having trouble working out the most efficient way of doing this. NSPropertyListSerialization appears to only support basic data types and from reading the docs, it looks as though NSCoder serialises / deserializes using its own format.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This library](https://github.com/psineur/NSObject-AutomagicCoding) enables you to save any object to a property list and [this one](https://github.com/jagill/JAGPropertyConverter) to JSON without making any additional effort. If you're wondering how they work, have a look at the [Archives and Serialization Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i).